# Writing colour coded XML code in HTML with <span> tag causing spaces

Tags: html, css, xml

I am working on a project and I need to display some XML on the web page. I am trying to colour code the XML using various span tags for the different xml parameters.

It is more a less working, but to keep the code tidy, I am putting each  tag on a new line. This is kind of working as each each tag stays on the same line, which is what I want unless I put a `<br />` tag but it puts a space in between each span tag.

For example, my XML is being shown as

```
<  Application  x  :  Class  ="YourApp.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

and I want

```
<Application x:Class="YourApp.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

Below is how I am trying to write the code in my HTML

```
<div class="codeBlock">
                        <span class="stringAndOperands"><</span>
                        <span class="xmltag">Application</span>
                        <span class="xmlParameter">x</span>
                        <span class="stringAndOperands">:</span>
                        <span class="xmlParameter">Class</span>
                        <span class="stringAndOperands">="YourApp.App"</span><br />
                        <span class="xmlParameter">xmlns</span><span class="stringAndOperands">="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"</span>
                    </div>
```

Below is my CSS

```
.xmltag
{
   color: #a31515;
   white-space: pre;
}

.stringAndOperands
{
    color: #0034ff;
    white-space: pre;
}

.xmlParameter
{
    color: #ff0000;
    white-space: pre;
}

.codeBlock
{
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    font-family: courier new;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

How can I remove the spaces when the span is on a different line. I know I can put each span on the same line would prevent this but this it makes my source code look a bit of a mess.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really, HTML automatically interprets line breaks as a single white space.  You basically need them all on the same line in the markup for there to truly be no white space.

However you can use CSS to kind of hack your way around it.  If you set `font-size: 0px` on the `.codeBlock` div and `font-size: 12px` or whatever on `span` the white spaces will not take up any space and it will fix your problem, assuming that you have no text inside `.codeBlock` that is NOT contained within a `span` element.

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fZPtM/)

Comment: @Boardy No problem :) please mark it as the approved answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: I will do, SO is making me wait 10 minutes before it will let me accept

Comment: note: if you are copying and pasting this code elsewhere, the spaces are still in it.  you just can't see them in the HTML page.

Comment: Yes, that is true and a drawback of this method. However the only other way I can see around it is to put the `spans` all on the same line, because as far as I know there's no way to prevent browsers from interpreting a line break as whitespace.

Comment: In an ideal world you'd be using some xml parser and javascript to add the colors and spans client side after the page has loaded to avoid this issue, but I'm guessing that's too involved for this case. There are tons of JS syntax highlighter scripts and plugins out there though.

Comment: Ah OK, I may look into that in the future at the moment its not a massive deal, its doing what I need but thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make sure you are using a reset to strip out any padding, margin etc.
span {margin: 0;padding: 0;border: 0;outline:0;vertical-align: baseline;}